# Can I tell camel jms endpoint to share jms connections between routes?

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel, connection-pooling, ibm-mq

I have a app server that runs multiple camel routes that are reading messages from a JMS Queue, each route runs with different selectors.

We have an app server for each group of clients. So at the end there are multiple connections created to the queue. And that seems to be affecting the read and write performance on the queue.

I tried to use a connection pool, (by the way i am using WMQ), the closest I got is to use spring's CachingConnectionFactory (as described in this post [how to configure (spring) JMS connection Pool for WMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086014/how-to-configure-spring-jms-connection-pool-for-wmq)).

I was hoping that the number of connections will reduce from each app server, but that did not happen. Even though i set the size to 5 on the CCFactory, i see 10 connections created to the queue. According to the documentation on CCFactory, explicit closing of the connections is required. Is it possible or does it even make sense to close the connection that is used by a camel route that is reading from a queue? Or is there a way to tell camel routes to share the connections? I thought the use of connection pool and factory will do that, but i don't see that from happening.

Can I achieve what I want to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is have only one route reading from the queue instead of many, and then use some camel conditional logic to redirect the message to the correct processing route via direct endpoints, see also this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691074/apache-camel-conditional-routing).

This way there would only one consumer for the queue, instead of multiple consumers each running it's own selector.

Comment: Yes i thought about it, but it is a very time consuming and risky task, and it is my plan for long term. for short term i am trying to find a quick solution, and thought the connection pool would solve it.