# Select between two webservices in apache camel

Tags: web-services, rest, apache-camel

I have two webservices WS1 and WS2 Is there any way in Apache Camel to select which services to call based on certain conditions?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691074/apache-camel-conditional-routing

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, for example content-based router.

```
RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("mock:error"));

        from("direct:a")
            .choice()
                .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
                    .to("direct:b")
                .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("cheese"))
                    .to("direct:c")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("direct:d");
    }
};
```

http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html