# How to run camel components in parallel

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I have a camel route **(main-route)**, which calls a soap web service and stores the result returned from soap service into database. My camel context is as below.

```
<route id="HttpRoute">
    <from uri="jetty:http://127.0.0.1:8889/Getdata"/>
    <to uri="direct:start"/>
</route>

<route id="TimerRoute">
    <from uri="timer://getdata?period=10000"/>
    <to uri="direct:start"/>
</route>

<route id="main-route">
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <process ref="soapRequestGenerator" />
    <marshal>
        <jaxb contextPath="org.sample.camel" fragment="true" namespacePrefixRef="namespacePrefixMap"/>
    </marshal>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <to uri="velocity:soapRequest.vm"/>
    <setHeader headerName="operationName">
        <constant>soapOperationName</constant>
    </setHeader>                      
    <to uri="cxf:bean:soapServiceEndpoint"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <process ref="soapResponseProcessor" />     //task-0
    <setBody>
        <simple>
            insert into table(Id,col1,col2) values(:?id,:?val1,:?val2);
        </simple>
    </setBody>
    <to uri="jdbc:dataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true"/>     //task-1            
    <to uri="velocity:soapResponse.vm"/>                        //task-2
</route>
```

Now there are two options to call **main-route**.

1) via timer(TimerRoute) which executes periodically and call the main-route to store data into database.

2)via http (REST) call which requires the returned response from soap service to be stored into db and returned to caller (REST).

Now i want to execute **task-1** and **task-2** of **main-route** in parallel when invoked via **HttpRoute** because they are independent. Data required by these two task can be prepared and stored into headers at task-0, but i don' know how to do this. Moreover i don't want to execute task-2 when main-route is invoke'd via **TimerRoute**. How to do that ?

I also want to check in to database before inserting the records received from soap service to avoid duplicate records into database. This check can be performed into parallel to soap service call (to increase throughput) and based on that need to decide weather records will be inserted or updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating the questions you've asked here

1. To follow different flows based on source route, you can set a header in the source route and use it in the main-route with [Router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) or [Choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691074/apache-camel-conditional-routing)
2. To run Task-1 and Task-2 in parallel, use [Multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html)
3. To run the Database check, use a DB processor. You can use [Multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) to fire the calls in parallel